# Advantages of having user authentication details stored in a separate table

Tags: database-design, database-optimization

I have a user table in mysql containing all user data (firstname, surname, address, etc)

But should I store the authentication details in another table (username, password) and link the two tables via a user ID?

Is there much point in this?

Is it more secure?

or does it just add extra coding?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there much point in this?

Nope, not at all.

> Is it more secure?

If someone can access your users table they can surely access whatever other table the passwords are on, so no.

> or does it just add extra coding?

Pretty much. You'll have to a lot of excess `JOIN`s to get the password info when there's really no reason to be dividing up the data in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there much point in this?

No.

> Is it more secure?

How could it be?  Database credentials apply to the whole database.

> just add extra coding?

Precisely.

Answer (score 0):

Reusing the answers template to add my 2 cents:

> Is there much point in this?

YES! it reduces overhead.If you only need to authenticate users, you don't need to fetch their profile info. It saves bandwidth and makes efficient tables.

> Is it more secure?

Nope

> or does it just add extra coding?

Well it is slightly more work but worth it as it's good Application Architecture. You're doing your future self a favor by designing a system that can scale.
Also if you work with a framework you won't feel it.

Comment: could you give an example setup or 2 of this to demonstrate?